# Partially applying mkdirp using Function.prototype.bind()

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns

I am reading a book on node design patterns, this is some code from page 99 [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=55WqDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=mkdirp%20partial%20application&source=bl&ots=A2JL9f1zFF&sig=FU2EzmZSFrGZHkfZ7_I8H2mHMeg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisrIbslfrWAhWFJlAKHaDsByoQ6AEILzAC#v=onepage&q=mkdirp%20partial%20application&f=false):

```
function download(url, filename, callback) { 
  console.log(`Downloading ${url}`); 
  let body; 

  async.series([ 
    callback => {                                    //[1] 
      request(url, (err, response, resBody) => { 
        if(err) { 
          return callback(err); 
        } 
        body = resBody; 
        callback(); 
      }); 
    }, 

    mkdirp.bind(null, path.dirname(filename)),       //[2] 

    callback => {                                    //[3] 
      fs.writeFile(filename, body, callback); 
    } 
  ], err => {                                        //[4] 
    if(err) { 
      return callback(err); 
    } 
    console.log(`Downloaded and saved: ${url}`); 
    callback(null, body); 
  }); 
}
```

I'm not following what happens at `//[2]`. The book says you are partially applying the function with bind. From my understanding from mdn [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), when you use `bind` you do not invoke the function.

How does this code work if you don't call `mkdirp()` later on? Is it referred to with the `callback` argument in `fs.writeFile`?

I have a potential solution to this. You hand `async.series` a list of functions that it will go through and execute. The mozilla mdn says that bind returns a function ready to be executed. If you use `call` or `apply` you are getting the result of the function. `async.series` wants a function to execute so you use bind to have it sat there ready without it running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misread the code. `mkdirp.bind(...` isn't called anywhere in the code, but inside the [`async.series`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series) call, and more precisely inside its parameter declaration (the array `[]`). `async.series` takes as argument an array containing function references and will call them in order, one after each other.

1. `//[1]` is called,
2. Then `//[2]` is called which is the reference to `mkdirp` already bound with the parameter (you can see an example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions))
3. And so on...

To make it clearer to you the code could have been written this way :

```
function download(url, filename, callback) {
  console.log(`Downloading ${url}`);
  let body,
    getFile = callback => {
      request(url, (err, response, resBody) => {
        if (err) {
          return callback(err);
        }
        body = resBody;
        callback();
      });
    },
    boundMkdirp = mkdirp.bind(null, path.dirname(filename)),
    writeFile = callback => {
      fs.writeFile(filename, body, callback);
    };

  async.series([
    getFile,
    boundMkdirp,
    writeFile
  ], err => {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    console.log(`Downloaded and saved: ${url}`);
    callback(null, body);
  });
}
```